# Setting global font size in kivy

Tags: python, properties, kivy, font-size

What is the preferred way, whether through python or the kivy language, to set the global font size (i.e. for Buttons and Labels) in kivy?

What is a good way to dynamically change the global font size setting in proportion to the size of the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [template](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#templates) to create your custom Label:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

kv = '''
[MyLabel@Label]:
    text: ctx.text if hasattr(ctx, 'text') else ''
    font_size: 24
    markup: True

<MyWidget>:
    id: f_wid
    BoxLayout:
        size: f_wid.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MyLabel:
            text: "Hello world 1"
        MyLabel:
            text: "Hello world 2"
        MyLabel:
            text: "Hello world 3"
        MyLabel:
            text: "Hello world 4"   
        MyLabel:
            text: "Hello world 1"
        MyLabel:
            text: "Hello world 2"
        MyLabel:
            text: "Hello world 3"
        MyLabel:
            text: "Hello world 4"   
'''
Builder.load_string(kv)

import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyWidget(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

To have font size depended on screen size, instead of using fixed values calculate it using `self.heigh`:

```
[MyLabel@Label]:
    text: ctx.text if hasattr(ctx, 'text') else ''
    font_size: self.height/2
    markup: True
```

**UPDATE**

Alternative approach is setting variable using #:set syntax:

```
kv = '''
#:set default_font_size "36sp"
<MyWidget>:
    id: f_wid
    BoxLayout:
        size: f_wid.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: "Hello world 1"
            font_size: default_font_size
        Label:
            text: "Hello world 2"
            font_size: default_font_size
        Label:
            text: "Hello world 3"
            font_size: default_font_size
        Label:
            text: "Hello world 4"   
            font_size: default_font_size
        Label:
            text: "Hello world 1"
            font_size: default_font_size
        Label:
            text: "Hello world 2"
            font_size: default_font_size
        Label:
            text: "Hello world 3"
            font_size: default_font_size
        Label:
            text: "Hello world 4"   
            font_size: default_font_size
'''
Builder.load_string(kv)
```

Comment: Thank you! Interesting approach. Out of curiousity, is there also a way to do it using kivy's own label construct, without defining a new type of object?

Comment: @James_L, there is nothing wrong with declaring new types. Anyway, I updated this answer as well.

Comment: Thanks again. It's not that I have anything against any particular approach. I've only been using kivy for a little while; learning multiple ways of doing things helps me in getting to know the framework a bit better.

Comment: Nice answer, i just want to point out kv templates (the [MyWidget@Widget] synthax) are being deprecated and replaced by the more powerful dynamic classes (<MyWidget@Widget> instead, and replace "ctx" with "root")).

Answer (score 15):

```
<Label>:
    font_size: dp(20)
    font_name: 'path/to/funcy/font.ttf'
```

Will set the font name and the font size globally for any widget that uses Label as it's base(TextInput and a few other widgets don't).

Comment: if you replace `<Label>` with `<Widget>` your font will be the default font for all other `uix.*` widgets.

Comment: Font sizes should be [expressed in sp, not dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981260/should-use-sp-instead-of-dp-for-text-sizes). Otherwise +1 for the helpful answer

Answer (score -2):

I know this question is old but you did ask about *"dynamically change the global font size setting in proportion to the size of the window"*

For a similar problem I've created **AutoSizedLabel**

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AutoSizedLabel(text="crazy stuff", ratio=0.5)
```

It is pip install-able by :

```
pip install kivyoav
```