# For setting font size what is most preferred in android sp, px or pt

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in android, I have a basichat doubt For setting font size what is most preferred in android sp, px or pt. Any help will appreciate

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981260/should-use-sp-instead-of-dp-for-text-sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sp: Scale Independent Pixel, scaled based on user’s font size preference.Fonts should use sp.
sp is preferrable for setting font size.

Answer (score 1):

Sp.  Sp is scaled pixels.  It scales with the text size the user sets.  This means that people with problems seeing can set a larger base font size, and your text will scale with that setting.  It makes it easier for those people to use the app.

Answer (score 1):

**SP Scale-independent Pixels**

Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommended you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user's preference.

for Refrence [more](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

Answer (score 1):

**Sp** for font size

**dp** for any view width, height, margin, padding etc.

**px** not recommended in android development

[for more detail read this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)